# How to add folders and files to electron build using electron-builder

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I am creating an electron which running react generated from create-react-app. Then i add nedbjs(a persistence database) and camojs(ODM for nedb) as dependency. To connect react with nedb i use electron ipc.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

And here is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "electron-pack": "build --em.main=build/electron.js",
    "electron-release": "build --em.main=build/electron.js --publish=always",
    "preelectron-pack": "yarn build",
    "preelectron-release": "yarn build"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.cra-electron-boilerplate",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "publish": {
      "provider": "github"
    }
  },
```

I use command yarn electron-pack to package my app. And then running the unpacked executable from dist folder then got this error:

[image]

Here is [my repo](https://github.com/afdallismen/electron-crud)

Comment: Your IDE looks beautiful

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Thank you. Its Atom, with file-icons package installed.

Answer (score 28):

To add a file or folder on your electron build folder, you can add the extraFiles options on package.json. 
Here is an example to copy a "credential" directory:

```
"build": {
  "appId": "com.example.electron-boilerplate",
  "files": [
    "app/**/*",
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "directories": {
    "buildResources": "resources"
  },
  "extraFiles": [
    "credentials"
  ],
  "publish": null
},
```

And then

```
$ npm run release // as usual
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I'm not finding `electron-builder` docs to be the clearest I've ever read. Does this example copy `resources/credentials` to `build/credentials`?

Comment: @GregK From the documentation: `extraFiles` `Array<String | FileSet> | String | FileSet`

The same as extraResources but copy into the app’s content directory (`Contents` for MacOS, root directory for Linux and Windows). Here is the link: https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extrafiles

Comment: In case it isn't clear to others as well, the way you access these files from your electron app seems to be with`process.resourcesPath`, and it seems you also have access to your electron repo at `${process.resourcesPath}/app/`

Answer (score 12):

I'm using a vue + electron library (https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder). I'm using the following:

- electron 5.0.13
- vue 2.6.10
- vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder 1.4.0

With that particular configuration, The following `vue.config.js` file was able to let me copy & paste a couple of directories from my project into the electron build:

**vue.config.js (works on my setup)**

```js
module.exports = {
    pluginOptions: {
      electronBuilder: {
        builderOptions: {
          // options placed here will be merged with default configuration and passed to electron-builder
          files: [
            "**/*"
          ],
          extraFiles: [
            {
              "from": "eepromStaging",
              "to": "eepromStaging",
              "filter": ["**/*"]
            },
            {
                "from": "src/assets/bin",
                "to": "src/assets/bin",
                "filter": ["**/*"]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So I **think** this is what's going on:

`**/*` is a glob pattern, which means "match all files". The `files: [**/*]` in `vue.config.js` will make your entire project directory available to the builder.  However, this doesn't mean that the files will be *in* your build directory: it just means that the files are *available* to the builder when building. If you didn't want the builder to have access to all files, then you'd replace the `**/*` with something else.

Regarding the installer that ultimately gets made and will be run by a user, the installer will create a directory on the user computer that mirrors the "build/win-unpacked" directory that gets made by `electron-builder`. At least this is the behavior in my setup. I'll refer to that as the "unpacked" directory.

The section called `extraFiles` will let you define extra files/folders that you can copy into your unpacked directory, from the files that are available to the builder. So I wanted to just copy this one folder called `eepromStaging` from my project root directory, into the unpacked root directory. And I also wanted to copy & paste this folder of binary files from my project into the unpacked directory. And these files are "extra": they're files that get added to your unpacked directory on top of everything else. The `"filter": ["**/*"]` means that all of the files and folders are going to be copied over.

I tested out the above configuration and it works for me: I'm able to make an exe installer that installs all my extra binary files in the correct location. However... in my configuration, I have to use `vue.config.js`, and if I try to add these properties to my `package.json`, it doesn't work. Ultimately though, these properties that I'm defining in `vue.config.js` simply get passed into the electron builder properties. So I think where you end up specifying these properties depends on your particular setup, but I think that these properties themselves should be the same. So maybe a solution for you would be to put this in your `package.json`, if you're just trying to copy over `database` directory, but I'm not sure.

**package.json (this may not work)**

```json
...
  "build": {
    "files": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "database",
        "to": "database",
        "filter": ["**/*"]
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Was running into issues with this as well, and found the `files` property to be the solution. This particular example copies a directory from my `node_modules` into the final build directory.

i.e. on Windows, it copies the files to: yourapp.exe/$PLUGINSDIR/app-64.7z/resources/app/

builder.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  productName: "myapp",
  appId: "com.reflex.app",
  directories: {
    output: "build",
  },
  files: [
    "package.json",
    {
      // SOLUTION
      from: "yourdirectoryorfilenamehere",
      to: "yourdirectoryorfilenamehere",
      filter: ["**/*"], // This will recursively include all sub-directories & files
    },
  ],
  // ... other configuration here ...
};
```

And then you can access the final files via a script in `src/renderer/` or `src/main`

```js
import { app } from "electron"; // For main process

/* 
Or use this instead for the renderer process: 
import { remote } from 'electron' // For renderer process
const { app } = remote
*/

const path = require("path");
const yourdirectoryorfilenamehere = path.join(app.getAppPath(), "/yourdirectoryorfilenamehere");
console.log(yourdirectoryorfilenamehere) // When built, this will show the path to where all your resources from (`files: []`) were saved
```