# en.json not found error on angular electron

Tags: angular, electron, angular-translate, angular8, electron-packager

I am developing an `Angular` + `Electron` project. In that I am using `angular-translate` functionality and I have an `en.json` file in the `/src/assets/i18n` folder. Everything works good on the browser.

**But when I run electron build, it is failed to load the `en.json` file. It is showing the error**

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

and it is referring to the url

> file:///assets/i18n/en.json

The `en.json` is actually located in `dist/myProject/assets/i18n` directory.

How can I fix this issue? I tried adding

> src/assets/i18n

in `asssets` in `angular.json` file. Then also there is no change in the result. How can I fix this? Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue. I added below code in app.module.ts

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this folder as a resource in your config? I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392642/how-to-add-folders-and-files-to-electron-build-using-electron-builder) answer.

Comment: I tried this. but this is not working. may be I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

The Electron app use the absolute path "./" after build. You must check the translate config to load the language files from the absolute path. I have changed "/assets/i18n" to "./assets/i18n" and all works fain.