# electronBuilder can't bundle my resource at all

Tags: vue.js, electron, bundle, electron-builder, electron-vue

It's my `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    pluginOptions: {
        electronBuilder: {
            preload: './src/preload.js',
                extraResources: ['resources/myengine'],
                "files": [
                "**/*"
                ],
                "extraFiles": [
                {
                    "from": "resources/myengine",
                    "to": "'./resources/app.asar.unpacked/myengine",
                },
                {
                    "from": "resources",
                    "to": "resources",
                    "filter": ["**/*"]
                }
        ]
    }
}
```

I try all solution to attach my resource but any result :(
note: `myengine` is `5mb` never added its size to my app.

BTW I read and try these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176263/1823003
- https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/76
- https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/539
- and etc.

Information:

- electron-builder  version=22.10.5
- build command `vue-cli-service electron:build`

So how could I solve my problem?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: you want `resources`, `files` and `extraFiles` available within the `app.asar` archive?

Comment: @customcommander plz ask clear, I didn't get, but my answer is no. I need out of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, need to use `builderOptions`:

```
module.exports = {
    pluginOptions: {
        electronBuilder: {
            builderOptions:{
                extraResources: [
                {from:'./src/resources/myengine',to:'./'}],
            }

        }
    }
};
```

One of them is enough :)